# Stop task at point in time - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I want to run a program in a time window. Let's say it should start at 07:00 am and end at 08:00 pm. The program does not end itself. It runs continually.

To do that I created a task in the task scheduler. I can configure a start time but there is no way of setting an end time. So I configured it to stop the task if it takes longer than 12 hours. This does end it at 07:00 pm which would be fine, too.

Problem is, if the task gets executed at a later time then the 12 hours limit exceeds the 08:00 pm limit. Is there any way to define that a task may not run later than a specific point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Create other Task that runs at 08:00 pm

In Actions: Initiate program

Program or Script : cmd.exe

Add Arguments: /c Taskkill /IM "Name of your program" /F

This command open cmd, kill the process of your program and close cmd window